# Unneeded hover action being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am attempting to have a dropdown menu 'drop' on hover, but it drops directly when I'm in the physical area of the dropdown menu even when it is hidden. I don't exactly know what I'm doing wrong here. Please help.

```js
/*Totally irrelavet javascript code here:*/
var rick = false;
var audio = new Audio('rick_roll.mp3');
var kkeys = [],
  konami = "38,38,40,40,37,39,37,39,66,65,13";
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  kkeys.push(e.keyCode);
  if (kkeys.toString().indexOf(konami) >= 0) {
    $(document).unbind('keydown', arguments.callee);
    if (rick == false) {
      rick = true;
      audio.play();
    } else if (rick == true) {
      rick = false;
      audio.stop();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
/*Some Fonts Here:*/
@font-face { font-family: Rusty; src: url('BrushScriptStd.otf');}
* {
 font-family: Rusty;
 font-weight: Lighter;
}
.background
{
 background-image: url(0.jpg);
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size: 100% auto;
 background-color: f7f7f7;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position:absolute;
}
.menubar
{
 height: 2.8vw;
 opacity: 0.85;
 background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
.clearfix:after {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
.menu-wrap {
    width:50%;
    box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background:#3e3436;
}
.menu{ 
    width:100%;
    margin:0px auto;
 text-align: center;
}
.menu li {
    margin:0px;
    list-style:none;
    font-family:'Ek Mukta';
}
.menu a {
    transition:all linear 0.15s;
    color:#919191;
}
.menu li:hover > a, .menu .current-item > a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: rgba(189, 34, 34, 1);
}
.menu .arrow {
    font-size:0.95vw;
    line-height:0%;
}
.menu > ul > li {
    float:middle;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    font-size:1.2vw;
}
.menu > ul > li > a {
    padding:0.7vw 5vh;
    display:inline-block;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
.menu > ul > li:hover > a, .menu > ul > .current-item > a {
    background:#2e2728;
}
.sub-menu li:hover {
    opacity:1;
}
.sub-menu {
    z-index: 99999;
    width:100%;
    padding:0px 0px;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0px;
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity linear 0.15s;
    box-shadow:0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background:#2e2728;
    z-index: -5;
}
.sub-menu li {
    display:block;
    font-size:1.2vw;
}
.sub-menu li a {
    padding:10px 10px;
    display:block;
}
.sub-menu li a:hover, .sub-menu .current-item a {
    background:#3e3436;
    z-index: 99;
}
.Rusty 
{
 font-family: "Rusty";
 color: rgba(189, 34, 34, 1);
}
.content
{
 margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    padding: 10px;
 height: 100%;
}
.menu > ul > .login 
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.video-container {
 position:relative;
 padding-bottom:56.25%;
 padding-top:30px;
 width: 100%;
}

.video-container iframe, .video-container object, .video-container embed {
 position:absolute;
 top:15;
 left:15%;
 right:15%;
 width: 25vw;
 height:25vh;
}
.title
{
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 7vh;
 text-decoration: underline;
 -moz-text-decoration-color: inherit; /* Code for Firefox */
    text-decoration-color: inherit;
}
.feed-column
{
 width: 50%;
}
.text-center
{
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="generator"
    content="HTML Tidy for HTML5 (experimental) for Windows https://github.com/w3c/tidy-html5/tree/c63cc39" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-subscribe-widget-webp-vflj9zwo0.css"
    name="www-subscribe-widget" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <title>RG - Home</title>
  </head>
  <body class="background">
    <div class="menubar">
      <nav class="menu">
        <ul class="clearfix">
          <li>
            <a href="aboutme.html">About Me 
            <span class="arrow">▼</span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li>
                <a href="#">Gaming</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Programming</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">YouTube</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Other</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="schedule.html">Schedule</a>
          </li>
          <li class="current-item">
            <a href="#">
              <p class="rusty">RedstoneGaming</p>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="equipment.html">Equipment</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a>
          </li>
          <li class="login">
            <a href="login.html">Login/Sign Up</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h1 class="rusty title">ThatRedstoneGuy&#39;s Feed</h1>
      <div class="feed-column">
        <h1 style="font-size: 3vh;" class="rusty text-center">Colortone | Am I colorblind?! | W/Voiceless</h1>
        <div class="video-container">
          <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-egJP-2ShRk?controls=2%20align="></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="feed-column"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see any menu dropping down in your example. `About Me` highlights when the mouse is below it, is that what you're talking about?

Comment: @Bamar Yes, can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
.sub-menu {
    opacity:0;
}
```

You've only made the submenu *invisible* you haven't made it *not there.*  You should use `display:none` instead, then to make it visible, `display:block`.